# How to search register in Pentaho with million registers

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

What is the best alternative to find a record among millions of records using Pentaho Spoon?
I'm using a 'stream lookup' with a 'table input', but my query on the 'tbResponse' step returns a lot of data, causing a lot of slowness. Has anyone ever experienced this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to use most of the records from the lookup table, the stream lookup is not the best option. Use a (merge) join operation instead, with both input streams sorted on the join keys.

If you only expect to use a low percentage of the records a database lookup is much better as it doesn't retrieve all of the records from the table, at the cost of many single select operations.

Answer (score 0):

If youren't processing a lot of records in your main data stream, you should use Database Lookup instead. That way it will only return the one record you need from the db, by using a specific field as key to find the correct record. However, it has the disadvantage of performing one query for each record you want to retrieve, so it might not be as good idea if you also have millions of records in your main stream. Anyway, that can be partially solved by caching some of the results in memory ("Enable cache?" checkbox and set number of records to store in cache).